# Apache mod_rewrite can't pass variable

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my rewrite rules work perfectly online (the site is up and running), but fail when I'm trying to run a local copy on my mac. I'm not using MAMP o LAMP and I have installed apache and php manually. Apache is 2.2.26 and php is 5.4.20.

There are more rules in my .htaccess file, but the ones I'm concerned about are these two:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Basically the variables are not being passed to the php file. Besides this, the rule below works perfectly fine! Even on my local setup I can't see any difference except the fact that I have two rules beginning with "^category/"

```
RewriteRule ^project/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ project.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Any clue why this works online (ubuntu) but fails locally?

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but just a tip, `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` can be shortened to `[\w-]+` as `\w` matches letters, digits and underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you have multiviews turned on. This causes mod_negotiation to fuzzy match requests to file-path resources. So when it sees `/category/something` and sees the file `category.php`, it sends the request right to the php file (in this case, ala PATHINFO) thus completely bypassing mod_rewrite.

Try turning multiviews off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```